# Preview while editing long latex blocks

Tags: latex, preview-latex

I need to edit latex for my math class. I'm currently using cdlatex mode w/ org-latex-preview functionality. The downside for me is that I can't see the equation as I'm editing it. I'd love to have a separate little buffer pop up so I can see what the rendered output looks like as I type. Otherwise, I get a little lost in the syntax. Exiting and re-entering the block is jarring.

Comment: You can take a look at this package: https://github.com/yangsheng6810/org-latex-impatient

Comment: @TianshuWang Can you add this as an answer? I'll accept it. This is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this package: [org-latex-impatient](https://github.com/yangsheng6810/org-latex-impatient) or [emacs-webkit-katex-render](https://github.com/fuxialexander/emacs-webkit-katex-render)